# How Blur video (or part of video) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have tried this way to blur a video in flutter, Unfortunately I couldn't.
I added the code that I tested,  as you can see the front image is blurred but the behind video doesn't,

this is what I have in my `stack`.

```dart
Positioned.fill(child: VideoPlayer(controller),),
Positioned.fill(child: Image.asset('assets/images/error.png',fit:BoxFit.contain,),),
Positioned.fill(child: BackdropFilter(filter:ImageFilter.blur(sigmaY: 6,sigmaX: 6),child: Container(),)),
```

you can see the result of my code, the front image is blurred but the behind video doesn't .

[image]